# using Python as ETL tool

Tags: python, etl

We are planning to use Python as ETL for one of our project.
Our requirement is as follows.

1. Wait for notification over Rabbit MQ for external system
2. As soon as MQ notification received, read the xml file (filesize can be from few KBs to 6GB file)
3. load the data in dataframe
4. sort dataframe on ID column
5. remove records with duplicate ID
6. perform some calculations on price, amount columns
7. insert data into database (MongoDB)
8. export the final output to csv file
9. Send MQ notification to external system that csv file has been generated

Note:
There will be many xml files coming in that has to be processed concurrently.

Also step 5,6 and 7 in above flow might be different based on the input file. So we will have separate flows for each file type.

Also we have to set the priority of file processing as well. If any high priority file comes in then the other file has to wait and the priority file has to be processed first.

We would like to have a suggestion on how can we design such system in Python which can be scalable and has a good performance ?
What are the tools that we can use ?

Comment: Hmm..., scalability can be a challenging question, but AFAIK the language is not the most relevant part. The priority part for example could be handled at RabbitMQ level by having different queues for different priority level and have readers to process high priority queues first. I'm afraid that this question is really broad...

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look to open source apache airflow that is developed by airbnb for Etl tasks
https://gtoonstra.github.io/etl-with-airflow/